# Laravel 4 Injecting an Eloquent Model in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to this concept of DI, and IoC so i might be doing this completely wrong but i am trying to inject the Model that matches a controller into that controllers constructor (UserModel -> UsersController) so that i can mock it later on.

So my model looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {


    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }


    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

}
```

And i am then trying to inject in UsersController like so :

```
class UsersController extends Controller {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //dd( $this->user);
        $users = $this->user->all();
        foreach ( $users as $user ) 
            print_r($user);
        return;
    }

}
```

Then when i hit this controller in the browser i get a "Unresolvable dependency resolving" error.

I noticed that this happend only when the class that i am trying to inject is a sub class of eloquent, if i try the same code with a custom class that do not extend eloquent then it works fine.

Am i missing something?

Comment: have a look into this screencast http://vimeo.com/53029232

Comment: @Raf thanks but it's actually the one that led me here, in that screen cast taylor does not show how to inject the actual model which is what i am trying to do

Comment: Did you try App::bind('UserInterface','User'); and put __controller(UserInterface $user)

Comment: Okay, I tried the scenario and I am getting the same result, an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments, I finally got to know that this is a complicated issue. To bypass this you need to bind your model with the IoC and return a new instance of your model manually.

```
App::bind('User', function()
{
    return new User;
});
```

Comment: Hey Raf, thanks i actually got that answer already from that thread : http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=3878